# How to find an equivalent to the following statement?

Tags: limits

The question is as follows-

We say that $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)$ exists as a real number is and only if $\exists L \in R , \forall \epsilon >0, \exists\delta>0, \forall x \in R, 0< |x-a|<\delta \implies |f(x)-L|< \epsilon$

Write a statement that **does not contain the negation sign**, which is **equivalent to** " $\lim_{x\to a} f(x) $ does not exist".

I started it by writing it down as follows-

$\lim_{x\to a} f(x)$ exists as a real number $\iff \exists L \in R , \forall \epsilon >0, \exists\delta>0, \forall x \in R, 0< |x-a|<\delta \implies |f(x)-L|< \epsilon$

Do I have to find the negation of $\exists L \in R , \forall \epsilon >0, \exists\delta>0, \forall x \in R, 0< |x-a|<\delta \implies |f(x)-L|< \epsilon$  ??

Is it really **equivalent** to "$\lim_{x\to a} f(x)$ does not exist as a real number" ?

Or is the answer something different?

Comment: I wish I could answer: $\liminf_{x \to a} f(x) < \limsup_{x \to a} f(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

A negation is obtained by changing $\forall$s to $\exists$s and vice versa and negating the statement on the right of them. Hence the negated statement is
$$
\forall L\in\Bbb R\quad
\exists \epsilon > 0\quad
\forall\delta > 0\quad
\exists x\in\Bbb R\colon 0<\lvert x-a\rvert < \delta,\text{ but } \lvert f(x)-L\rvert \ge \epsilon.
$$

Comment: The question asks about a statement equivalent to "Limit dies not exist". Is the above negation really equivalent to the given statement?

Comment: It is exactly equivalent to the statement that the limit does not exist. More precisely, it claims that any $L\in\Bbb R$ cannot be the limit. For whatever $L$ we take, there exists an $\epsilon > 0$ such that no matter how small we make $\delta > 0$, there is always an $x\in \Bbb R$ with $0 < \lvert x - a\rvert < \delta$ that does *not* satisfy the relation $\lvert f(x)-L\rvert < \epsilon$. Hence we have $\lvert f(x) - L\rvert\ge\epsilon$ instead.

Comment: Oh I get it. Thanks